# how to loop through collection and save to db

Tags: c#

I'm having some issue with executing the database by looping through two collection that I have. Mind you that this is just an example.

1st collection include: genders - male, female
2nd collection include: names - john, james, mike, stacy, paula

I've used for loop for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < genders.count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0, j < names.count; j++)
    {
        //call to stored procedure there
        //parameters
        //execute
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest on how to do this differently?

Comment: How to do _what_ differently? What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: what issue? what database?

Comment: I would say this is an extremely inefficient way to interact with the database. It would be better to create a single query and send that in one go to the database, alternatively, build up a set of parameters and send them to the database. [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) is a good read, even if you are not on SQL Server.

Comment: @Oded I agree. One database hit would be the biggest single way to improve the code in the question. That's why I asked about the database, I have done this in both sql server and oracle (although sql server is more straightforward). Another option (but not as good) would be to ensure there's a single connection wrapping those stored proc calls, as generally it is setting up the connection that takes the most time. But ideally...one roundtrip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an issue, but if you're asking if your approach is improvable, yes.

I would simply use a class with these properties(inclusing gender).

```
class Person
{
    public bool IsFemale { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create a **single** collection, for example a `List<Person>` and loop that.

```
var persons = new List<Person>() { 
    new Person{IsFemale=false, Name="john"},new Person{IsFemale=false, Name="james"},
    new Person{IsFemale=true, Name="stacy"},new Person{IsFemale=true, Name="paula"}
};

foreach(Person p in persons)
{
    //call to stored procedure there
    //parameters
    //execute
}
```

**Edit**: If you have problems with the ADO.NET part, here's an example:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", typeof(string));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", typeof(string));
    con.Open();
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@Gender"].Value = person.IsFemale ? "female" : "male";
        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = person.Name;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, why not create your own class?

```
class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String sex;

    public Person(String name, String sex)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public String Sex
    {
        get { return sex; }
        set { sex = value; }
    }
}
```

Then create a list of people

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.add(new Person("Ashley", "Male"));
```

Then a foreach loop...

```
foreach(Person p in people)
{
Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " " + p.Sex);
}
```

Your question is very vague but thats what i would do...